# How to query cloudant db when there is an array in the json document

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have some json docs in cloudant DB like the following records.

> {"@dataType":"GroupItem", "name":"aGroupName1", "GroupType":0},
>            {"@dataType":"GroupItem", "name":"aGroupName2", "GroupType":1, "Users":[{"deviceUUID":"id1", "userName":"user1"},{"deviceUUID":"id2", "userName":"user2"}] }

They are for groups and the users that belong to the group.
I want to do a query to return the groups the login user belongs to.

So when "user1" login, I'd like to see both "aGroupName1" and "aGroupName2" being returned.

The condition is like:
Select group when GroupType == 0 or (GroupType == 1 and userName == loginUser)

Because the userName is in an array in the json, I don't know how to do the query in Cloudant. Appreciate your help!

Jen

Comment: You would need to create a view.  Have you created any views yet?  You will need to use be secondary indexes in Cloudant to be able to query on two indexes.  Check out https://cloudant.com/for-developers/search/.

Comment: Thanks. Let me add more info. This is a ios app. And I have a replicated local dbstore. So I'd like to use CDTDatastore.find() method. 
https://github.com/cloudant/CDTDatastore

Comment: You said, "So when 'user1' login, I'd like to see both 'aGroupName1' and 'aGroupName2' being returned." However, in your example it appears that "user1" only belongs to "aGroupName2" and not "aGroupName1". Can you either provide an updated example, or explain how "user1" also belongs to "aGroupName1" in your example? Also, can you make clearer in your example which data is stored in separate documents and which data is all in one document?

Comment: Hi Bardley, there are 2 types of the group. "aGroupName1" is a public group (groupType=0), so even it has no user listed, but any login user can get it.

I can not format it :-( If you look at the JSON bracket,  line 1 is one document and line 2 and line 3 are another document.

So the idea is public group don't need to list any user, it is available to all the users. But private group needs to list its members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a map function like the following that emits a compound key:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc["@dataType"] == "GroupItem") {
    doc.Users.map(function(user) {
      emit([user.userName, doc.name]);
    });
  }
}
```

This will let you query by `userName` and find all of the matching group `name` values. Add `GroupType` to that compound key if you also need to query by group type.

Comment: I created a View under Design Docs using your function. I also created an index using "function (doc) {
  index("name", doc.name);
}". When I did a query using "{
  "selector": {
    "username": {
      "$eq": "jen"
    }
  }
}". It says "There is no index available for this selector."

Comment: @ZhengXie If you're trying to use Cloudant Query, then I'd suggest starting by using the dashboard where you can define an index by picking which fields to index.